# Last item in the array not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In this script: last item is not selected to apply colorMe function

```
var k =0;
var userarray = [];
var dayarray  = [];
var dayarray2 = [];
var dayarray3 = [];
var data = 0;
function colorMe(param,param_af,param_eve, param2)
{


    /*console.log("DAY "+param);
    console.log("user "+param2);*/
    //console.log("k= "+k);
    console.log("data= "+data);

    userarray.push(param2);
    //console.log("mY "+userarray[k]);
    dayarray.push(param);
    dayarray2.push(param_af);
    //console.log("afternoon "+dayarray2[k]);
    dayarray3.push(param_eve);
    //console.log("evening "+dayarray3[k]);
    //console.log("Day "+dayarray[k]);
    var len = userarray.length;
    console.log("K= "+k);

    for(;data < k;data++)
    {
        //console.log("data="+ data);
    var arr = dayarray[data];
    var arr2 = dayarray2[data];
    var arr3 = dayarray3[data];

    $("div.morning_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });


            $("div.afternoon_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr2.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });
            $("div.evening_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr3.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });

    }
```

**
//This identifies the last item, can anything be done here to apply color on matching string like the rest?
**

```
    if(data == (localStorage.size-1)){
alert("data"+data+" k= "+k+"size= "+localStorage.size+"user= "+param2+"morn= "+param+"aftr="+param_af+"eve="+param_eve);    

    }
    k++;
}
```

T'm trying to color only the last item in the array. How do I do that? Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axpbe377/2/

HTML structure

```
<div id='1'>
User 1234

<div class='morning_1234'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

<div class='afternoon_1234'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

<div class='evening_1234'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

</div>
<br/><br/>
<div id='2'>
User 4455

<div class='morning_4455'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

<div class='afternoon_4455'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

<div class='evening_4455'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

</div>
<br/><br/>
<div id='3'>
User 9868

<div class='morning_9868'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

<div class='afternoon_9868'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

<div class='evening_9868'>
<span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: you have to add `data=0` in the `colorMe` method .

Comment: @Taplar, no typo, the other is evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/axpbe377/3/

```
<div id='1'>
  User 1234

  <div class='morning_1234'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

  <div class='afternoon_1234'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

  <div class='evening_1234'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='2'>
  User 4455

  <div class='morning_4455'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

  <div class='afternoon_4455'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

  <div class='evening_4455'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='3'>
  User 9868

  <div class='morning_9868'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

  <div class='afternoon_9868'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

  <div class='evening_9868'>
    <span>Mon</span><span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span><span>Thrs</span><span>Fri</span><span>Sat</span><span>Sun</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var data = [{
    user_id: 1234,
    morning: 'Sat,Sun',
    afternoon: 'Tue,Thrs,Sun',
    evening: ''
}, {
    user_id: 4455,
    morning: 'Thrs,Fri,Sun',
    afternoon: 'Tue',
    evening: 'Mon'
}, {
    user_id: 9868,
    morning: 'Tue,Wed',
    afternoon: 'Tue',
    evening: 'Fri,Sun'
}];

data.forEach(function(user) {
    var mornings = user.morning.split(',');
    var afternoons = user.afternoon.split(',');
    var evenings = user.evening.split(',');

    $("div.morning_" + user.user_id + " span").filter(function() {
        return mornings.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');

    $("div.afternoon_" + user.user_id + " span").filter(function() {
        return afternoons.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');

    $("div.evening_" + user.user_id + " span").filter(function() {
        return evenings.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');
});
```

If you want to have your function call...
https://jsfiddle.net/axpbe377/5/

```
data.forEach(function(user){
    colorMe(user.morning, user.afternoon, user.evening, user.user_id);
});

function colorMe(param, param2, param3, user_id){
    var mornings = param.split(',');
    var afternoons = param2.split(',');
    var evenings = param3.split(',');

    $("div.morning_"+ user_id +" span").filter(function(){
        return mornings.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');

    $("div.afternoon_"+ user_id +" span").filter(function(){
        return afternoons.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');

    $("div.evening_"+ user_id +" span").filter(function(){
      return evenings.indexOf(this.innerHTML) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');
}
```

Comment: from what you explained, I edited my code as in the post above (look at EDITED colorMe) but its not targeting the div's correctly to affect the span within them

Comment: yes thats right, I'm passing in globalStore.data[i].user_id for instance

Comment: But the colorMe doesn't color the matching class of span with the supplied array of string for each div for all items now.

Comment: added the explanation

Comment: just noticed your edited post..I tried but it doesn't color any of the item.

Comment: I think this should, just that, can I know how to call this function to supply parameter?

Comment: @yes Taplar :( sorry yar, I really have hard time doing this

Comment: or wait..instead of passing to a function can it be done within the for loop? that was making the function call?

Comment: That's pretty much what the forEach is doing.  If your iterating over an array you want to use forEach() instead of a normal for()

Comment: here's the fiddle for the loop which making call to colorMe.  https://jsfiddle.net/eqmL32vv/

Comment: @Keren jumping off for the night.  I added the colorMe into the answer and a link to a fiddle using it.  If you want to keep your for() shouldn't be too hard to make them work together.